# RDS Not Accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

I have multiple MariaDB RDS instances.

1. All are in the same VPC
2. All are publicly accessible.
3. All are in the same security groups including a rule to allow MySQL/MariDB (3306) 0.0.0.0 and my current IP.
4. Same subnet
5. Same availability zone.

I can connect to one but not the other. I tried rebooting I tried restoring snapshot to new instance. With the same exact configuration as the working (which is pretty much the same config for all). Still does not work. Database is accessible internally from EC2. Also was working a few days ago. The only thing that changed was my locations IP after an outage. But considering I can connect to another RDS port 3306 is not blocked. Any ideas?

Tried changing the security group to 0.0.0.0 tried restarting tried restoring from snapshot was expecting to be able to access

Comment: What is the experience trying to connect? using CLI? what is result - timeout? error?